# Still struggling with handling large data set

Tags: r, memory-management, data.table, ff, r-bigmemory

I have been reading around on this website and haven't been able to find the exact answer. If it already exists, I apologize for the repost.

I am working with data sets that are extremely large (600 million rows, 64 columns on a computer with 32 GB of RAM). I really only need much smaller subsets of this data, but am struggling to perform any functions besides simply importing one data set in with fread, and selecting the 5 columns I need. After that, I try to overwrite my dataset with the specific conditions I need, but I hit my RAM cap and get the message "Error: cannot allocate vector size of 4.5 GB. I looked at ff and bigmemory packages as alternatives, but it seems like you can't subset before importing in those packages? Is there any solution to this problem besides upgrading RAM on computer?

Tasks I am trying to perform:

```
>SampleTable<-fread("my.csv", header = T, sep = ",", select=c("column1", "column2", "column7", "column12", "column15"))

>SampleTable2<-SampleTable[SampleTable[,column1=="6" & column7=="1"]]
```

At this point, I hit my memory cap. Would it be better to try and use another package but import all 64 columns of 600 million rows? I also don't want to spend hours upon hours just to perform one import.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are lots of resources to read in large memory. Take a look at the [ff package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html). Also, you are not overwriting your data frame called SampleTable, you are creating a new one called SampleTable2.

Comment: Store your data in a database, and retrieve only the bits you need, when you need them.

Comment: So to be sure to understand correctly, you have a file with 600M lines and 64 columns by line. And, you want to read this into a data frame keeping only 5 columns out of the 64 and also applying a filter on rows?

Comment: And, are all the 5 columns numeric?

Comment: @shayaa Sorry I have tried both, one where I created a new one "SampleTable2" and one where I try and overwrite "SampleTable" but I still get the same error

Comment: @F.Privé Yes, all the columns should be numeric based

Comment: @swads Can you answer to my first question as well?

Comment: To save on memory, the second stage should use SampleTable <-, and not create SampleTable2, as @shayaa pointed out. As you used fread from R's data.table library SampleTable will be a data.table. The syntax of the second line would be improved by rewriting using data.table's syntax: `SampleTable<-SampleTable[column1=="6" & column7=="1"]`

Comment: @F.Privé Yes to your first question

Comment: @HywelMJ Even when writing SampleTable<- in the second stage, it still gets the error of "cannot allocate vector of size 4.5 GB"

Comment: Even when rewritten as I suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is read the CSV file in chunks:

```
# Define only the subset of columns
csv <- "my.csv"
colnames <- names(read.csv(csv, header = TRUE, nrows = 1))
colclasses <- rep(list(NULL), length(colnames))
ind <- c(1, 2, 7, 12, 15)
colclasses[ind] <- "double"

# Read header and first line
library(dplyr)
l_df <- list()
con <- file(csv, "rt")
df <- read.csv(con, header = TRUE, nrows = 1, colClasses = colclasses) %>%
  filter(V1 == 6, V7 == 1)
names(df) <- paste0("V", ind)
l_df[[i <- 1]] <- df

# Read all other lines and combine
repeat {
  i <- i + 1
  df <- read.csv(con, header = FALSE, nrows = 9973, colClasses = colclasses)
  l_df[[i]] <- filter(df, V1 == 6, V7 == 1)
  if (nrow(df) < 9973) break
}
df <- do.call("rbind", l_df)
```

`9973` is an arbitrary prime number which has few chance to be a divisor of `nlines - 1`.

Comment: Great answer, did exactly what I needed it to. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If your dataset can be easily parsed (no embedded commas for example):

```
library(data.table)

> fread('cat tmp.csv')
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12 col13 col14 col15 col16 col17
1:    6    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
2:    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
> fread("cat tmp.csv | awk -F ',' 'NR == 1 || ($1 == 6 && $7 == 1)'")
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12 col13 col14 col15 col16 col17
1:    6    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
> fread("cat tmp.csv | awk -F ',' 'NR == 1 || ($1 == 6 && $7 == 1) {print $1, $2, $7, $12, $15}'")
   col1 col2 col7 col12 col15
1:    6    1    1     1     1
>
```

Comment: Use of awk is only going to work with Unix/Linux, not Windows

Comment: @zacdav added the relevant library call

Comment: @HywelMJ true, and cat also, although that's beside the point.

Comment: @ClaytonStanley I am running this on windows, any way to get around this issue?

Comment: @swags A Cygwin install.