# How to skip first n rows while reading a .csv file in R

Tags: r

I have a 5GB .csv file to be analysed, I was thinking of reading it chunk by chunk nad than process a chunk at a time. so was trying to skip those many lines which are already been read. this code is not working, it only reads first chunk successfully, after that it doesn't reads garbage value for the following iterations. need help with the code...

```
ReadCsvChunk <- function(ffName,chunk.num,chunk.size){

    cnt = 1
    nskip = 0
    rCnt = chunk.size

    repeat {

         x <<- read.csv(file = ffName, nrows = rCnt, skip = nskip, header = T)

         # ...
         # analyse here 
         #....

        nskip = nskip + chunk.size

        if(cnt == chunk.num | nrow(x) < chunk.size){
            break
            }
        cnt = cnt+1

    } #repeat

}#function

ReadCsvChunk("WHO.csv",2,10) # read 2 chuck each of 10 rows
```

Comment: What is your question or what problem are you having?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strategies for reading in CSV files in pieces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352887/strategies-for-reading-in-csv-files-in-pieces)

Comment: Maybe take a look at `read.chunk` in the `iotools` package.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45418297/6103040

Comment: @lmo thanks that worked