# R - Read large file with small memory

Tags: r, performance, csv, memory, large-file-upload

My data is organize in an csv file with millions of lines and several columns. This file is to large to read into memory all at once.

Fortunately, I only want to compute some statistics on it, like the mean of each column at every 100 rows and such. My solution, based on other posts where was to use read.csv2 with options nrow and skip. This works.

However, I realized that when loading from the end of the file this process is quite slow. As far as I can tell, the reader seems to go trough the file until it passes all the lines that I say to skip and then reads. This, of course, is sub optimal, as it keeps reading over the initial lines every time.

Is there a solution, like python parser, where we can read the file line by line, stop when needed, and then continue? And keeping the nice reading simplicity that comes from read.csv2?

Comment: Take a look at `readLines`

Comment: I don't know how `read.csv` is implemented, but it might require sequential access of the input file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Still struggling with handling large data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362126/still-struggling-with-handling-large-data-set)

Comment: `read.csv` is very slow. It's not suitable for large files. I usually use `data.table::fread`.